# How do I get Palm's WebOS browser to default to numeric input?

Tags: css, webos, palm-pre, palm

The following CSS worked fine in my Windows mobile phone, but my Pre won't default to numeric inputs.

```
input.numeric {
 -wap-input-format:"*n";
}
```

How do I get the Pre (and presumably other newer mobile browsers?) to default to numeric inputs?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but the new `number` value for the `type` attribute introduced in HTML5 does work on the Mobile Safari:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="2" value="6" />
```

Reference: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#type-number

Comment: No dice on Palm's Browser, although I'm sure my iPhone users will appreciate the update.  Thanks.